What is the minimum Auto Page Refresh admin interval for Direct Query models in a Power BI Pro licensed workspace?
I have configured auto page refresh to occur every minute on my Power BI report. Understandably, what actually ends up happening is the page is only able to refresh as frequently as the 'admin interval' limit, which is enforced by the service.
According to the documentation:

Shared workspaces. For regular workspaces (workspaces that aren't part of a Premium capacity), automatic page refresh has a minimum interval of 30 minutes (the lowest interval allowed).

Automatic page refresh in Power BI Desktop - Power BI | Microsoft Learn
What I am actually seeing, is the admin interval is set to 5 minutes:

Given that I have a Pro licensed workspace (i.e. shared capacity workspace), should I be prepared for the minimum interval change to 30 minutes as per the documentation? Or is 5 minutes a new value here for the admin interval in shared capacity workspaces?

30 mins is the best you will get for Pro, even setting the admin level to less that that it should still be 30mins. Anything less requires a Premium/Fabric capacity, which then uses the admin defined interval

That was my understanding @Jon, so really don't understand why I am seeing the Admin interval and page refreshing every 5 minutes in the Pro workspace!
